# Why does MQTT keep disconnecting after it connects to a host on swift

Tags: swift, tcp, mqtt

I have produced an app that connects to a raspberry pi's own wifi network and sends a message to give some data to it. I was using the cocoamqtt Library found [here](https://github.com/emqx/CocoaMQTT) but I couldn't find a way to know when the client connects successfully or not so I move to the Moscapsule Library found [here](https://github.com/flightonary/Moscapsule). I could easily connect to my pi with the cocoamqtt library, but whenever I try to connect to the pi with the Moscapsule library it just says 'Received DISCONNECT from iDevice' as soon as it makes a connection.

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import Lottie
//import CocoaMQTT
import Moscapsule
import Firebase

class DeviceSetupLoadingConnectionViewController: UIViewController {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let connectedRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: ".info/connected")
    connectedRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        if let connected = snapshot.value as? Bool, connected {
            print("Connected")
        } else {
            print("Not connected")
        }
    })

    connect()
}

func connect(){
    let mqttClient = MQTTConfig(clientId: "iDevice", host: "192.168.4.1", port: 1883, keepAlive: 60)
    let client = MQTT.newConnection(mqttClient)
    client.subscribe("PSK", qos: 0)

}
```

The log:

```
1564204025: mosquitto version 1.6.2 starting
1564204025: Using default config.
1564204025: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1564204025: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1564204027: New connection from 192.168.4.1 on port 1883.
1564204027: New client connected from 192.168.4.1 as Pi (p2, c1, k60).
1564204027: No will message specified.
1564204027: Sending CONNACK to Pi (0, 0)
1564204027: Received SUBSCRIBE from Pi
1564204027:     PSK (QoS 0)
1564204027: Pi 0 PSK
1564204027: Sending SUBACK to Pi
1564204033: New connection from 192.168.4.9 on port 1883.
1564204033: New client connected from 192.168.4.9 as Bdz3SjkBU0 (p1, 
c1, k0).
1564204033: No will message specified.
1564204033: Sending CONNACK to Bdz3SjkBU0 (0, 0)
1564204033: Received SUBSCRIBE from Bdz3SjkBU0
1564204033:     PSK (QoS 0)
1564204033: Bdz3SjkBU0 0 PSK
1564204033: Sending SUBACK to Bdz3SjkBU0
1564204033: Received DISCONNECT from Bdz3SjkBU0
1564204033: Client Bdz3SjkBU0 disconnected.
```

Comment: Hard coded clientId's are a bad idea as they have to be unique

Comment: @hardillb would that be the source of my problem and how would I get around that then?

Comment: If you have more than one device connect to the broker with the same clientId it will kick the oldest one off. If they have auto reconnect logic then they just cycle round kicking each other off the broker. How you generate unique clientId values is entirely up to you, they just have to be unique.

Comment: @hardillb The IOS device still keeps on disconnecting after it connects even when I have a unique id every time?

Comment: The logs show that the client is explicitly asking to disconnect.

Comment: @hardillb why though? My code shows that I'm not telling it to disconnect. I can even send a message and subscribe to a topic but it disconnects straight after.

Comment: You've not shown us enough your code to comment, there isn't even where it subscribes to a topic in what you shared. (p.s. I don't do iOS stuff anyway)

Comment: @hardillb it shouldn't be anything to do with iOS, that's the whole of my code that connects to the raspberry pi but it just disconnects straight away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb here since I've never used Swift.

The only reference to the mqtt client object `client` is as a local variable in the `connect()` method.

Once this method returns the `client` object will go out of scope so will become eligible for Garbage Collection. I would assume that the `client` object has a destructor that calls disconnect before it is actually destroyed, hence the immediate disconnect.

The fix is to make sure there is a reference to the `client` object that lives as long as you need it to.

Comment: I found in the console log of Xcode this statement '[MOSQUITTO] DEBUG   Client OvYqvPMOqz sending DISCONNECT'. Would that mean anything?

Comment: Only that it confirms that the client is explicitly disconnecting. I stand my assumption in the answer.

Comment: by my understanding, the client object never gets destroyed by my understanding

Comment: of course it does, as soon as the `connect()` method returns there is no reference to it

Comment: I'm sorry I must be being dumb then, how would I keep the client object alive for however long I need it alive for then?